# How to add "_blank" attribute to ftp links?

Tags: http, ftp, target

I have the following script that adds target="_blank" to all "http" and "https" links:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body a[href^='http']").attr("target","_blank");
});
```

Example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uBk8s/)

How to add to this script the "ftp" links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the second attribute you want to match against separated by comma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body a[href^='http'],[href^='ftp']").attr("target","_blank");
});
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5uHY/)

Comment: Thank you.
It turns out, this was so simply.